# simple method returns in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, cocos2d-iphone, getter

I am currently new to objective c and have came across a problem while making a game I have a custom made object called battleEngine which is an instance variable in my helloWorld scene in cocos2d. That object has an object as an instance variable called plyController which is a PlayerController object. I want battleEngine to have a getter method that returns the plyController object and this code doesn't work:

```
-(PlayerController*)getPlayerController
{
 return plyController;
}
```

Comment: how do you mean, it doesn't work? have you declared `-(PlayerController*)getPlayerController;` in the .h file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any reason you haven't just declared your player controller object as a property? You could just use the synthesised getter in that case to get the player controller.

Have a look at the documentation on [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Also, and I'm afraid I have to say this or they will take my Cocoa-programmer badge away from me, `getPlayerController` is not a good method name. Methods with `get` in them are conventionally used to return values in the parameters passed in by reference. The [Cocoa Coding Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF) tells us this, and much more.